# PERL dynamically match arrays based on unique key

Tags: arrays, perl, dictionary

I'm trying to compare 2 huge arrays and want to use map. I am using unique key concept here to match the indexes.

My Arrays:

```
my @array1 = ( ['a','b','c','d'], ['e','f','g','h'], ['i','j','k','l'], ['m','n','o','p'], ['q','r','s','t']);
my @array2 = ( ['r','q','s','t'], ['b','a','c','d'], ['n','m','o','p'], ['f','e','g','h'], ['j','i','k','l']);
```

My unique Keys:

```
my @uk1 = (0,2,3);
my @uk2 = (1,2,3);
```

These arrays will be huge in size, over 30,000 indexes in each with over 20 elements in each index.

So effectively i create a map where

```
for ( my $j = 0; $j <= $#array1 ; $j++ )
{
    my searchString;
    for ( my $k = 0; $k <= $#uk1; $k++ )
    {
       if ( $k != 0 )
    {
     $searchString .= ","
    }
      $my searchString .= $array1[$j][$uk[$k];
    }


    my @result = map { $_ }
        grep { join (",",$array2[$_][1],$array2[$_][2],$array2[$_][3]) ) =~ join(",",$array1[$j][0],$array1[$j][1],$array1[$j][2]) }
    0 .. $#array;
}
```

returns matched indexes.

My problem is, how do i make this dependant on the unique keys? as the length of the unique key will keep changing and as far as i know i cannot dynamically create the $array2[$_] join part.

Hope my question is clear enough.

I want to have the logic that compares

```
$array1[$uk1[0]],$array1[$uk1[1]],$array1[$uk1[2]] and so on (depending on the number of keys in UK) with 
$array2[$uk2[0]],$array2[$uk2[1]],$array2[$uk2[2]].......
```

Comment: I don't see how `@uk1` values correspond to what you're doing in the map.

Comment: That's what i want to implement, can't understand how

Comment: uk1 points to: $array1[0][0] = a, $array1[0][2] = c, $array1[0][3] = d ===> a,c,d. Similarly uk2 points to: $array2[1][1] = a, $array2[1][2] = c, $array2[1][3] = d ===> a,c,d which is what we wanted to match

Comment: Btw, 30000 items of 20 pieces each these days is not really **huge**.  Maybe 30000000 items would be.

Comment: @woolstar it might scale up to that, hence i want to fix the issue right now before it becomes too huge to handle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps,

```
my @array1 = ( ['a','b','c','d'], ['e','f','g','h'], ['i','j','k','l'], ['m','n','o','p'], ['q','r','s','t']);
my @array2 = ( ['r','q','s','t'], ['b','a','c','d'], ['n','m','o','p'], ['f','e','g','h'], ['j','i','k','l']);

my @result;
for my $i (0 .. $#array1) {
  push @result,
    map { [$i, $_] }
    grep { 
      "@{ $array1[$i] }[1,2,3]" eq "@{ $array2[$_] }[0,2,3]"
    }
    0 .. $#array2;
}

use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \@result;
```

output

```
$VAR1 = [
      [
        0,
        1
      ],
      [
        1,
        3
      ],
      [
        2,
        4
      ],
      [
        3,
        2
      ],
      [
        4,
        0
      ]
    ];
```

Comment: sorry but its giving me anything back

Comment: @Suyash can you post how `@result` should look like?

Comment: i need index of array1 and index of array2. In this case it'll give me ([0,1],[1,3],[2,4],[3,2]). Oh and your "@{ $array1[$_] }[0,1,2]"
 should be "@{ $array1[$_] }[0,2,3]"
for this example. i tried after changing that but my @return is coming as empty

Answer (score 1):

What you want to use is an array slice:

But lets also make life easier:

```
for my $sample ( @array1 )
{
  my $test= join(",", @$sample[@uk1]) ; 
  my @result = grep { $_ eq $test } map { join(",", @$_[@uk2] ) } @array2 ;
  say "huzzah" if @result ;
}
```

Perl lets you specify multiple elements from an array via the "array slice":

```
my @list= ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd') ;
my @pieces= @list[1,3] ;
```

Comment: How do i make it return the index instead of the values, right now it gives me the matched values for each iteration. like a,c,d
e,g,h
i,k,l
m,o,p
q,s,t
instead i want the index.